# Editing a record using lwc record-edit-form does not submit values

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I am new to lwc and trying to create a lwc for updating contact record fields. I am using the lightning-record-edit-form component. But, when I try to submit the form nothing happens, no errors and the form resets the value back to the old ones. What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

````
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            Contact Info
        </h3>
        <template if:true={contactId}>
              <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={contactId}  object-api-name="Contact"  onsuccess={handleSuccess}  onsubmit={handleSubmit}>  
                    <lightning-messages>  
                    </lightning-messages>  
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">  
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-left_xx-small">                              
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">  
                            </lightning-input-field>  
                        </div>  
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-left_xx-small">  
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">  
                            </lightning-input-field>  
                        </div>  
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-left_xx-small">  
                            <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone">  
                            </lightning-input-field>  
                        </div> 
                    </div>  
                    <lightning-button  
                        class="slds-m-top_small slds-p-left_xx-small slds-align_absolute-center"  
                        variant="brand"  
                        type="submit"  
                        name="update"  
                        label="Update">  
                    </lightning-button>  
                </lightning-record-edit-form>  
           <!-- </template>  -->
        </template>
        <template if:true={error}>
            {error}>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>```


JS:

    import getUserInfo from '@salesforce/apex/UserDetails.getUserInfo';
    import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
    import { getSObjectValue } from '@salesforce/apex';
    export default class ContactCard extends LightningElement {
    
        @track contactId;
        @track contacts;
    
        @wire(getUserInfo, {userId: Id})
        wiredContact({data,error}) {
    
            if (data) {
                this.contactId = data.Id;
                this.data = data;
                this.error = undefined;
            } else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
                this.data = undefined;
            }
     }   
    
        handleSuccess( event ) {  
            console.log('Inside Success Event ....');  
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({  
                title: 'Contact Updated',  
                message: 'Contact Updated Successfully!!!',  
                variant: 'success'  
            }); 
            
            this.dispatchEvent( toastEvent );  
        }  
    
        handleSubmit(event){
            console.log('Inside Submit Event ....');  
            event.preventDefault();
            const fields = event.detail.fields;
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);   
        }
    }
````

Comment: Why have you implemented handleSubmit instead of leaving it to process this directly? Do you need to? Does it work if you remove this?

Comment: as Phil pointed out, this may be your problem. onSubmit combined with `event.preventDefault()` means it never gets handled so you manually calling submit actually just re-enters the same function! Removing the call to `handleSubmit` should fix it!